# Take integral using integration by part

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives, partial-derivative, self-learning

Let us take its integral

$$\int_0^xF(z)dz$$

Note that F() is distribution function.

I used integration by parts.

By I can obtain a trivial result.

I know it’s easy question but I cannot do it.

Integration by parts means
That is

I choose u=F(z) then du=dF(z)

dv=dz then z=v

And so on.

Comment: integration by parts on what?

Comment: I added @gimusi

Comment: intehration by parts is useful when you have an integral in the form $$\int_0^x f(z)\cdot g'(z)\,dz=[f(z)\cdot g(z)]_0^x-\int_0^xf'(z)\cdot g(z)\,dz$$

Comment: This question really needs more context. This integral just jumped from the sky or what? And that $F$ is a distribution function does not say anything informative except that the integral is well defined. Moreover $F(z) $ doesn't  have to be differentiable. Please improve the question. Where did this question came from?

Comment: @shashi in fact this is game theory proof question. I did not share all question. But if you want I can write all question. Thank you.

Comment: @Dothisdone yes do it, please! What I see now is like asking "how can I do integration by parts?" because the property of $F$ being JUST a distribution function does not add any anything useful. You don't even tell what other properties $F$ has...

Comment: Dear @Shashi I asked the question again https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2614123/question-on-calculation-of-integral Hopefully you will help me.

Comment: Looks much better. However, it is not my level. How the new question is built will surely attract many people that are willing to help you. Have a nice day!

Comment: @Dothisdone Please, if you are ok, you can accept the answer and set it as solved. Thanks! cdn.sstatic.net/img/faq/faq-accept-answer.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case you could apply integration by parts in thi way

$$\int_0^xF(z)\cdot 1\,dz=[F(z)\cdot z]_0^x-\int_0^xF'(z)\cdot z\,dz$$

Comment: Okay and the second integral result?

Comment: I obtained similar. But what is the second part integral?

Comment: Without integration by part, how can find this integration in the question box? Integration by part is only suggestion. It may be false.

Comment: @Dothisdone It depends on the function, for example for $F(z)=\log z$ it is a good way to integrate, but not always.

Comment: @Dothisdone what is the expression for F in your case?

Comment: There is no expression. Therefore I ask.

Comment: @Dothisdone In general the derivative of the CDF is the PDF

Comment: Dear gisumi can I write it in this way? The actual integral is this $\int_0^1\int_0^X F(z)dzdx=\int_0^1(F’(x)-F’(0))dx=\int_0^1F’(x)dx=\int_0^1dF(x)$

Comment: I asked all question about this integration. If you look at it I will be happy https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2614123/question-on-calculation-of-integral