# Question on calculation of integral.

Tags: calculus, integration, self-learning, game-theory

> > I need to show this proof
>
> $$\int_0^1\int_0^xF(z)dzdx\le \int_0^1\int_0^xG(z)dzdx$$ if and only if $F$ has Lower variance than $G$ for the same mean of $F$ and $G$ and with support $[0,1]$.

Also I know that by the second order stochastic dominance definition

$\int_0^x F(T)dT\le \int_0^x G(T)dT \iff \int u(x) dF(x) \ge \int u(x) dF(x)$

The solution is as follows:

[image]

But I cannot reach from this integral

> $$\int_0^1\int_0^xF(z)dzdx\le \int_0^1\int_0^xG(z)dzdx$$

to this integral

$U(F)= \int u(x)dF(x) \ge U(G)= \int u(x)dG(x)$

How can I get this last integral from the integral in yellow box? I asked this way.

Comment: See here: www.princeton.edu/Notes04, in page 5 you have "definition 2" which is different from your definition of mean preserving spread. Also, theorem 2' tells you what you need: if u is concave, then int u dF(x) <int u dG(x) (in the whole line! Not for every subintegral as in the definition) .

Comment: @AndreaMarino unfortunately page doesn’t work.

Comment: @AndreaMarino okay I found but how to prove it? I didn’t understand what you said. Please show it ? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

A MPS ia such that $S(x) =\int^x F(z) dz < \int^x G(z) dz T(x) $. Recall that for any $u\in C^{\infty} $ you have the integration by parts formula

$$\int^b u(x) dF(x) = (boundaryterms)(u, F) - \int^b u'(x) F(x) dx = (boundaryterms) +\int^b u''(x) S(x) dx =(*) $$

If $u$ is concave $u''$ is always negative, so the inequality $S \le T$ yields

$$ (*) \ge (boundaryterms) (u, F) + \int^b u''(x) T(x) dx $$

To get the equality between boundary terms, you must use the boundary condition of MPS's, the endpoint of the interval you are working on. Using this and the same passages, you get

$$ (*) = \int^b u(x) dG(x) $$

Which conclude the proof.

Comment: I don’t understand how you add S(x) in the integral in the 3rd line?

Comment: S(x) is the integral of the F! It is ordinary integration by parts

Comment: In fact does not make sense. How did you use the integral in the yellow box of question box in order to obtain your result?

Comment: Thank you so much for helps :)

Comment: You use the definition of MPS okay. But you don’t use the double integral in the question.

Comment: Can I post what I did? Can you check it?

Comment: I don't understand. In the page you linked, apparently there is no hypothesis regardind that double integral, isn't it?

Comment: Of course you can, but I don't anything of the subject but the definitions involved.